# hibernate3-maven-plugin Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa

I'm trying to use the hibernate3-maven-plugin to read the JPA entites in my persistence.xml and create the DDL database script so that I can insert my tables into my database.  The first maven plugin configuration below works and creates the DDL script but the pom.xml has an annoying lifecycle configuration error when viewing it in Eclipse.  I attempted to use the second configuration of the plugin below (the one with the lifecycleMappingMetadata) but it doesn't create the DDL script and doesn't throw any erros when I mvn clean install.  Any ideas?

**Eclipse XML Validation Error:**

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl (execution: default, phase: 
 compile)
```

**Works but has Eclipse XML Validation lifecycle configuration Error:**

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                                <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <persistenceunit>myapi</persistenceunit>
                            <outputfilename>my.sql</outputfilename>
                            <drop>false</drop>
                            <create>true</create>
                            <export>false</export>
                            <format>true</format>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

**lifecycleMappingMetadata that doesn't work:**

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
         <configuration>
           <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
             <pluginExecutions>
               <pluginExecution>
                 <pluginExecutionFilter>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <versionRange>[2.2,)</versionRange>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                   </goals>
                 </pluginExecutionFilter>
                 <action>
                   <ignore />
                 </action>
               </pluginExecution>
             </pluginExecutions>
           </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
           <components>
                <component>
                    <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                    <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                </component>
            </components>
            <componentProperties>
                <persistenceunit>denaliapi</persistenceunit>
                <outputfilename>denali.sql</outputfilename>
                <drop>false</drop>
                <create>true</create>
                <export>false</export>
                <format>true</format>
            </componentProperties>
         </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: When such error happen I normally Ctrl+1 or right click and add exception to the pom.xml. You can also add permanent exception to eclipse setting so it'll never happen again. This is ofcourse if you don't bother about m2e not recognizing the lifecycle

Comment: @gerrytan - I didn't have that option available in eclipse kepler

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle mapping that should be ignored is m2e's, not hibernate3's.  Use your first block to configure hibernate-maven3, and use this block for m2e:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
  <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
          <pluginExecutionFilter>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <versionRange>[2.2,)</versionRange>
            <goals>
              <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
            </goals>
          </pluginExecutionFilter>
          <action>
            <ignore />
          </action>
        </pluginExecution>
      </pluginExecutions>
    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If the DDL is not being generated after that change, try changing the `<ignore/>` to `<execute/>`.

(Aside:
The Ctrl+1 suggestion that @gerrytan made works in Kepler.  Is your caret on the line with the error?)